# PyQt How can I prevent hovering over a QMenu from clearing the Qstatusbar?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qmenu, qstatusbar

I am using the `QStatusBar` to print information for how many items are in a list.

This works well, however when I hover over any of the `QMenu` icons it clears all data from the QStatus, leaving it blank.

I'm working in windows, and I believe that it's something native that I need to break the connection of that keeps trying to update the statusbar with new information, as I wasn't having this issue while running my window from Maya.

Any ideas for how I could fix this would be great!
I'd rather not create a new widget to hold this information.

Comment: You could display the code that updates the statusbar

Comment: That's just the standard behaviour of [QStatusBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html#details).

Comment: @eyllanesc, yeah! I tried that using self.menuString.menuAction().setStatusTip('test'), but it only makes the test flag up while you're hovering over the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to

Simplest way is to add `QLabel` to status bar, set it's `stretch` to a non-zero value and change Label's text instead.

```
self.status_label = QtGui.QLabel()
self.ui.statusbar.addPermanentWidget(self.status_label, 100)
self.status_label.setText('wow such label')
```

Another way is to install event filter on QStatusBar, either via subclassing or monkey patching. 
Example of the latter:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.statusBar().eventFilter = self.event_filter
        self.installEventFilter(self.statusBar())
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def event_filter(_, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.StatusTip:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: I ended up going with the label option in the end, less faff all round. Thanks!